# Pandas Regex extract giving different output to re.search?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, python-re

So, I'm trying to use regex to extract weight values from a column of my pandas dataframe...expect for some reason, it's not extract right.

```
all_data["name"].iloc[0] = "220 grams" # this is purely to show my issue

pattern  = "[0-9]+ ?(gram|mg|Gram|GRAM)"

gram_values = all_data["name"].str.contains(pattern)

re.search(pattern, all_data["name"].iloc[0])
```

Output is

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 8), match='220 gram'>
```

As predicted, it's exporting the 220 gram.  Hooray.

NOW, if I use the pandas.str.extract method...

```
all_data["name"].str.extract(pattern)
```

Then the output is

[image: extracts "gram"]

Same regex pattern, two different outputs.  So what the hell am I doing wrong here?  How can the regex string extract different values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas [`Series.str.extract()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) behavior is explained in the documenation, it returns only the [*capturing group*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) contents.

> `pat : string` 
>   *Regular expression pattern with capturing groups*

Your regex contains a single capturing group, `(gram|mg|Gram|GRAM)`, so its contents are returned.

To make the regex work in Pandas `str.extract`, wrap it with a capturing group, and make the other [group *non-capturing*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions):

```
r"([0-9]+ ?(?:gram|mg|Gram|GRAM))"
# |        |non-capturing group||
# |_______ capturing group______|
```